# extracting a number in a line with sed

Tags: sed, sh

I'm trying to get a Value out of a information block.

I'm creating the following output:

```
RSSI: -21
RSSI: -12
RSSI: -13
RSSI: -13
RSSI: -16
RSSI: -13
```

with following command:

```
hcidump -a | egrep 'RSSI|bdaddr' | grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'bdaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' | egrep 'RSSI'
```

But i would like to get only the Value at the end to be displayed.
But I'm struggling with the right pattern, I found many hints online, but not one that will work, e.g.:

```
sed 's/RSSI: //'
```

Further I would like to know if there is a smoother way of my command on the top, because it seems with every | the output is getting slower, like it fills a buffer before it outputs the values.

PS: i wanna use this command in C with the system() function, is there an option to get the value to be stored in a C-variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
hcidump -a |.. whatever...:XX:XX'|grep -Po 'RSSI:\s+\K.*'
```

or

```
hcidump -a |.. whatever...:XX:XX'|awk '/RSSI/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for `sed`, you can use `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 myfile
```

This will output only the 2nd column, considering one whitespace as column delimiter.

Edit: to delete whitespaces at the beginning of each line in *myfile*, do this first:

```
sed -i 's/^ *//' myfile
```

Comment: it does not work with me, but the reason is I forgot to mention whitespaces before RSSI.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you have variable number of spaces in between, you can use following:

`rev myfile | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev`

Comment: the two rev s make no sense. since you have used `cut -fx`, you can just take the 2nd field...

Comment: But what if the input contains something like `RSSI: <space> <space> -21` i.e. Multiple blank spaces in between? It'll not return the last number then.

Comment: if that is the case, either squeeze the spaces (by tr for example) or use other tool other than cut (e.g. awk) . I won't choose rev and rev back. It perhaps was the slowest way.

Comment: in my case there should be always the same amount of spaces in between. Suggestions for the other "problems"'?

Comment: did not even try, cause I already have performence issues because of the number of pipes (I assume) and that woould be even more pipes.